# Dynamic LINQ Sub Query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I have LINQ query that I want to generate dynamically:

```
var groupData =
    from l in data
    group l by l.Field1 into field1Group
    select new MenuItem()
    {
        Key = field1Group.Key,
        Count = field1Group.Count(),
        Items = (from k in field1Group
                 group k by k.Field2 into field2Group
                 select new MenuItem()
                 {
                     Key = field2Group.Key,
                     Count = field2Group.Count()
                 }).ToList()
    };
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to dynamically group the data by any combination of fields with no limit on the nested queries.

I can get as far as the first level but I'm struggling with the nested sub queries:

```
string field1 = "Field1";
string field2 = "Field2";

var groupDataD =
    data.
    GroupBy(field1, "it").
    Select("new ( it.Key, it.Count() as Count )");
```

Is this possible with chained dynamic LINQ? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can build complex queries dynamically using expression trees. Here's a very short sample of what can be achieved: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries and the `Expression` class, which is what you'll be using to build your dynamic queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @DaveW, did my answer help you solve your issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help further.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work (though personally I would rather avoid using such code):

1. Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43272944/3002584) to add the following in `ParseAggregate`, :

   ```
   Expression ParseAggregate(Expression instance, Type elementType, string methodName, int errorPos)
   {
      // Change starts here
      var originalIt = it;
      var originalOuterIt = outerIt;
      // Change ends here

      outerIt = it;
      ParameterExpression innerIt = Expression.Parameter(elementType, elementType.Name);
      it = innerIt;
      Expression[] args = ParseArgumentList();

      // Change starts here
      it = originalIt;
      outerIt = originalOuterIt;
      // Change ends here

      ...
   }
   ```
2. Add `Select`, `GroupBy`, `ToList` into `IEnumerableSignatures`, and respective conditions in `ParseAggregate`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26079675/3002584):

   ```
   interface IEnumerableSignatures
   {
     ...
     void GroupBy(object selector);
     void Select(object selector);
     void ToList();
     ...
   }

   Expression ParseAggregate(Expression instance, Type elementType, string methodName, int errorPos)
   {
      ...
      if (signature.Name == "Min" || 
          signature.Name == "Max" || 
          signature.Name == "GroupBy" || 
          signature.Name == "Select")
      ...
   }
   ```
3. Finally, Your query would be:

   ```
   string field1 = "Field1";
   string field2 = "Field2";

   var result =
       data
       .GroupBy(field1, "it")
       .Select($@"new ( 
          it.Key,
          it.Count() as Count,
          it.GroupBy({field2})
            .Select(new (it.Key, it.Count() as Count))
            .ToList() as Items
       )");
   ```

   Note that `"it"` holds a different instance when used in the parent query vs. the subquery. I tried to take advantage of `"outerIt"` to overcome this conflation, but unfortunately without success (but maybe you'd succeed? maybe [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39876867/3002584), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30944975/3002584) would help)
4. A simple example for future reference:

   ```
   public class Person
   {
       public string State { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
   }
   public static Main()
   {
       var persons = new List<Person>
       {
          new Person { State = "CA", Age = 20 },
          new Person { State = "CA", Age = 20 },
          new Person { State = "CA", Age = 30 },
          new Person { State = "WA", Age = 60 },
          new Person { State = "WA", Age = 70 },
       };
       var result = persons
           .GroupBy("State", "it")
           .Select(@"new ( 
              it.Key,
              it.Count() as Count,
              it.GroupBy(Age)
                .Select(new (it.Key, it.Count() as Count))
                .ToList() as Items
           )");
        foreach (dynamic group in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Group.Key: {group.Key}");
            foreach (dynamic subGroup in group.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"SubGroup.Key: {subGroup.Key}");
                Console.WriteLine($"SubGroup.Count: {subGroup.Count}");
            }
        }
   }
   ```